# filter that forwards to index page

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat7

I want to make a filter that would forward to `/WEB-INF/index.html` request to application that looks like this

```
http://localhost:8080/basic-application-web
```

Here is my filter

```
public class RootFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {}

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        if (req.getRequestURI().equals("/basic%2Dapplication%2Dweb/")) {
            req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/index.html").forward(req, resp);
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {}
}
```

My `web.xml` looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
         xmlns='http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee'
         xmlns:web='http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd'
         xsi:schemaLocation='http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaeeweb-app_2_5.xsd'
         id='basic_web' version='2.5'>
    <display-name>Basic web application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>serviceServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.pack.ServiceServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>serviceServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/messaging</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>rootFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.pack.RootFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>rootFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

However from time to time I get some weird behaviour where `tomcat` (I use it to deploy the war) is unable to find `basic-application-web` when I try to access directly using URL.

Though through tomcat manager it works fine. What is the problem? Maybe due to missing `root` servlet?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? 404?

Comment: Yup. Though I think I solved the problem by moving `index.html` outside `WEB-INF`

Comment: PLease mark your question as solved after posting the answer that worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved `index.html` outside `WEB-INF` so basically the layout started to look like this

```
webapp
    WEB-INF\web.xml
    index.html
```

And adjusted `filter` to forward to `/index.html` instead of `WEB-INF/index.html`

```
req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/index.html").forward(req, resp);
```

It has helped.